# Failed to build image "ERROR: Worker process (11579) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down..."

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, yocto, bitbake

I am an software engineer in Askey. I have one question about building the apq-8053 device image. The main question is that I can not build well.
Below  is the error messages which show unexpected shutdown. 
I have studied from the web site and google and found the following links shows that

https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6570
[https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/WW35_-*2014-08-26*-*Weekly*-_1.7_M3](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/WW35_-_2014-08-26_-_Weekly_-_1.7_M3)

yocto seems provide an updated version and has fix this kind of issue. So how can I get the updated one for fixing this problem ?Why this happened ? Does it relate to the workstation hardware requirement? How Can I fix this problems ? What Information should I provide for the judgement about this issue ?

```
paultsai@paultsai-VirtualBox:~/poky/build$ build-8053-image

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.28.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-14.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "aarch64-oe-linux"
MACHINE           = "apq8053"
DISTRO            = "msm"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "LV.HB.1.1.2-24200-8x96.0"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "aarch64"
TARGET_FPU        = ""
meta-qti-bsp-prop = "HEAD:2ff9d30dac1d0734547b0793bd5d1efb00d00f4e"
meta-qti-bsp      = "HEAD:1d1ee2d6a9b1b8d949aaaace89e561145938f55b"
meta-yocto        
meta              
meta-yocto-bsp    = "HEAD:2ff9d30dac1d0734547b0793bd5d1efb00d00f4e"

ERROR: Worker process (11579) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
ERROR: Fakeroot process (18615) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
ERROR: Worker process (11579) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
ERROR: Fakeroot process (18615) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
ERROR: Worker process (11579) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
ERROR: Fakeroot process (18615) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
ERROR: Worker process (11579) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
ERROR: Fakeroot process (18615) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
'/home/paultsai/poky/build/bitbake.lock']' returned non-zero exit status 1
/home/paultsai/poky/build
paultsai@paultsai-VirtualBox:~/poky/build$
```

Thanks and Best Regards